# This code prints a list of months and their high and low temperatures. How can I use the update function? Check under code for explanation

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main():
    #temperature data for Aurora:
    highTemps = [-3, -2, 3, 11, 19, 23, 26, 25, 20, 13, 6, 0]
    lowTemps = [-11, -10, -5, 1, 8, 13, 16, 15, 11, 5, -1, -7]
    weatherDB = createDB(highTemps, lowTemps)  


    for m in weatherDB: 
        for t in weatherDB[m]: 
            print(m, t, weatherDB[m][t])

    m = input("Enter a Month Name: ")
    if m in weatherDB: 
      print(weatherDB[m])
    else: 
      print("Month not found")

'part 2'
def tempByMonth(weatherDB, month):
    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    weatherDB = {}

    for i in range(len(months)):
      month = months[i]
      weatherDB[month]

    return weatherDB

'part 4'
def update(weatherDB):
    #complete this code according to the assignment instructions
    update = input("What would you like to update: ")
    newhigh = input("What new high temperature do you want: ")
    newlow = input("What new low temperature do you want: ")

    return




#DO NOT change this function:
def createDB(highTemps, lowTemps):
    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    weatherDB = {}

    for i in range(len(months)):
        month = months[i]
        weatherDB[month]={"high":highTemps[i],"low":lowTemps[i]}
    return weatherDB



main()
```

This code prints a list of months and their high and low temperatures. How can I use the update function to ask for what new and low temps they want and print a new list with the updated months? Ive put the inputs for the month they would like to update and the new and low temperatures they want but I dont know how to print out the same list of months and temperatures but with the updated ones.

Comment: `Aurora` as in Aurora 4x?

Comment: Yes I just want the same month and temperatures but with updated ones depending on which month and temp they wanted to update

Comment: There's no clear mapping, how are you supposed to achieve the goal?  For example, how to you tell your user input `month`? A few simple input/output (expected outcome) will help. (It seems that you re-post the same question)❓

Comment: Output should just look like the same list of months and temperatures but replace the month and temp that they inputted with updated ones

Answer (score 0):

Just read input until it is correct:

```py
def str_is_int(inp_str: str) -> bool:
    try:
        int(inp_str)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True


def update(weatherDB: weather_db_type) -> None:
    month: str = ""
    while month not in MONTHS:
        month = input("What would you like to update: ")

    new_high_raw: str = ""
    while not str_is_int(new_high_raw):
        new_high_raw = input("What new high temperature do you want: ")

    new_low_raw: str = ""
    while not str_is_int(new_low_raw):
        new_low_raw = input("What new low temperature do you want: ")

    weatherDB[month]["high"] = int(new_high_raw)
    weatherDB[month]["low"] = int(new_low_raw)
```

full code, rearranged and typed:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Dict

MONTHS: Tuple[str, ...] = ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",)

weather_db_type = Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]


def create_db(highTemps: Iterable[int], lowTemps: Iterable[int]) -> weather_db_type:

    weather_db: weather_db_type = {}

    for i in range(len(MONTHS)):
        month = MONTHS[i]
        weather_db[month] = {"high":highTemps[i], "low":lowTemps[i]}
    return weather_db


def str_is_int(inp_str: str) -> bool:
    try:
        int(inp_str)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True


def update(weatherDB: weather_db_type) -> None:
    month: str = ""
    while month not in MONTHS:
        month = input("What would you like to update: ")

    new_high_raw: str = ""
    while not str_is_int(new_high_raw):
        new_high_raw = input("What new high temperature do you want: ")

    new_low_raw: str = ""
    while not str_is_int(new_low_raw):
        new_low_raw = input("What new low temperature do you want: ")

    weatherDB[month]["high"] = int(new_high_raw)
    weatherDB[month]["low"] = int(new_low_raw)


def main() -> None:
    #temperature data for Aurora:
    high_Temps = [-3, -2, 3, 11, 19, 23, 26, 25, 20, 13, 6, 0]
    low_temps = [-11, -10, -5, 1, 8, 13, 16, 15, 11, 5, -1, -7]
    weather_db = create_db(high_Temps, low_temps)


    for m in weather_db:
        for t in weather_db[m]:
            print(m, t, weather_db[m][t])

    m = input("Enter a Month Name: ")
    if m in weather_db:
      print(weather_db[m])
    else:
      print("Month not found")

main()
```